# Creating a new Dialog and setting it to be modal properly masks everything behind it when displayed

Tags: extjs

Creating a new Dialog and setting it to be modal properly masks everything behind it when displayed. However tab navigation is not disabled. You can still hit tab to go through the items in the main window and hit keys to execute events. I think this should be disabled as well since the reason why you set the dialog to be modal is to prevent any kind of interaction with other elements different than those in the Dialog.

Comment: can you give us a screenshot? seriously, I have never seen this occur!

Answer (score 1):

This is standard browser behaviour, because the controls are not disabled behind the mask and hence the tab action is still valid.

Looks like [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?29231-2.0.1-OPEN-modal-dialog-can-be-bypassed-by-tab-pressing) has been [an issue for a while](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7964-Modal-dialogs-can-be-bypassed)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is to disable the other controls, or you might also be able to use a LoadMask on your Tab Panel to mask the controls.

Comment: How can I do it? Could you give an example?